# Wordpress Multisite on Nginx giving 404 for files

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

Hello I have set up a WordPress multisite on LEMP stack using VPSSIM

I have migrated this setup from another server which was running on Apache.

Like if you see this  website ( http://goo.gl/U5xNSV ) that is part of WordPress multisite, you will see many 404 erros in the page. It gives 404 error for many files.

Here is the Config file for the main Domain in Multisite   http://goo.gl/Xy5uuq

I followed this tutorial and added Nginx Helper WordPress plugin but nothing happened.

Link to tutorial : http://www.itworld.com/article/2871918/how-to-configure-nginx-for-wordpress-multisite-with-subdirectories.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to try EasyEngine command-line tool (https://rtcamp.com/easyengine/)

Once EasyEngine is installed, execute following command to setup WordPress Multisite with Nginx FastCGI caching enabled.

```
ee site create example.com --wpsubdom --wpfc
```

EasyEngine is the most popular Nginx server setup project to setup Nginx, PHP, MySQL, HHVM and Pagespeed in single line command to serve more user traffic.

Free community support (http://community.rtcamp.com/c/easyengine) is also available if you get stuck anywhere.

Comment: Thanks  @dineshjain2911. Thank you for your answer.  I know about Easy Engine but the problem is that it does not supports CentOS. It supports only Ubuntu and Debian. Any alternate solution available.

Comment: Hello, I have setup EasyEngine on Ubuntu 14.04. Everything is working fine but I am confused with domain mapping. How do I do domain mapping ?